# Moderncv shorthand URL in header

Tags: hyperref, moderncv, links

I'm using `moderncv` to write my CV and I'd like to use a shorthand link in the header of my CV. The command `\httplink` has an optional argument to do this, but this argument is not passed to `\homepage`.

How can I redefine `\homepage` to pass the shorthand link as an optional argument to `\httplink` in the `\maketitle`  command without messing everything up?

An example of what I was thinking of is

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\renewcommand*{\homepage}[2]{\def\@homepage[#1]{#2}}

\firstname{John}
\lastname{Doe}

\homepage[shorthand]{long link that I'd like to mask}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Except that I don't if that is the proper way to redefine `homepage` and this code doesn't redefine line 265 of `moderncvclassic.sty` where, as far as I can tell the argument of `homepage` is passed to `httplink`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to patch `\makecvhead` *after* loading the `classic` style using something like [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) (already loaded by the class).

I've done so below, replacing the `\httpslink{\@homepage}` piece with a conditional based on whether you supplied a shorthand argument `<desc>` or not through the updated `\homepage[<desc>]{<URL>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}% <cmd>
  {\httpslink{\@homepage}}% <search>
  {{\ifx\@homepage@shorthand\relax
     \httpslink{\@homepage}% Used \homepage{<URL>}
   \else
     \httpslink[\@homepage@shorthand]{\@homepage}% Used \homepage[<desc>]{<URL>}
   \fi}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\RenewDocumentCommand{\homepage}{o m}{%
  \let\@homepage@shorthand\relax%
  \providecommand\@homepage{#2}%
  \IfValueT{#1}{\def\@homepage@shorthand{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\firstname{John}
\lastname{Doe}

\homepage[shorthand]{long_link_that_id_like_to_mask}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine, except for urls containing `&`. In that case I get an error (`href@split has an extra }`). I looked it up, and the solution seems to be enclose the \href{} commange in {}. How would you do it in your solution?

Comment: @Kpantzas: See the updated solution.

Comment: Great! Applied the same patch to `makelettertitle`, it works like a charm!

Comment: I'm almost a decade too late, by now this MWE does not work anymore. Can you update the solution to recent changes in the moderncv class (or whatever else is not working anymore)?

Comment: One more remark: This solution works fine for the CV, but when I generate the cover letter in the same document, the url is not masked there. Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: @And: Can you provide a minimal example that sets up your environment? That way I have something to work with.